# The best approach to calculating SSD wear with crystaldisk command line

Tags: command-line, ssd, powershell, crystaldiskinfo

I installed crystaldiskinfo (Version 8.17.3) on a windows pc, and then ran the following command line function.

```
cmd > "%ProgramFiles%\CrystaldiskInfo64.exe" /CopyExit
```

This gives me a text file in the same directory with the following information:

```
   [...] 
-- Disk List ---------------------------------------------------------------

 (01) Samsung SSD 850 PRO 512GB : 512.1 GB [0/0/0, pd1] - sg

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (01) Samsung SSD 850 PRO 512GB

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Model: Samsung SSD 850 PRO 512GB
        Firmware: EXM02B6Q
   Serial Number: S250NXAG967403Z
       Disk Size : 512.1 GB (8.4/137.4/512.1/----)
     Buffer Size : Unknown
     Queue Depth : 32
    # of Sectors : 1000215216
   Rotation Rate : ---- (SSD)
       Interface : Serial ATA
   Major Version: ACS-2
   Minor Version : ATA8-ACS version 4c
   Transfer Mode : SATA/600 | SATA/600
  Power On Hours : 15593 hours.
  Power On Count : 124 times
     Host Writes : 5032 GB
Wear Level Count : 20
     Temperature : 28 C (82 F)
   Health Status : Good (99 %)
        Features : S.M.A.R.T., NCQ, TRIM, DevSleep
       APM Level : ----
       AAM Level : ----
    Drive Letter : C:
```

My question is the following.

What would be the optimal indicator in this list to determine the wear of the SSD?

Comment: "Health Status : Good (99 %)" What are you actually worried about? Drives work until they don't. SMART might give you a hint, but then again it might not. I've had HDs & SSDs die in a year, others still going after a decade. You'll know for sure once it dies… that's why we have backups; because you never know when.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not afraid of anything, in fact I'm just trying to make statistics on our 400 machine computer park, to get an idea of which SSDSs are very worn out, and where we need particular attention. But you're right about the substance

Comment: A good value you can monitor is `Host Writes`. You are currently at 5TBW and your drive has a guarantee of 300 TBW (according to Samsung web page for Pro 850 512GB). So you can calculate yourself...